# Notation for all the interactions between two sets of variables (in matrices)

Tags: matrices, notation

I have two matrices: X of size $n\times K$ and $Z$ of size $n \times J$. I want to define a matrix $M$ made of all the possible interactions between the $K$ variables in $X$ and the $J$ variables in $Z$. I have no problem to code this theoretically, but I would like to know what is the simplest possible notation to write this down, is there a matrix operation I can use, or a special type of matrix product (like the Hadamard or Kronecker but a different one)?
The only way I found is to write it "explicitly", i.e., I define:
$X = [ x_1, ..., x_K ]$ where $x_1$ is a column/variable of size $n\times 1$.
$X = [ x_1, ..., x_K ]$ where $x_1$ is a column/variable of size $n\times 1$.
and then,
$M = [x_1*z_1, x_1*z_2, ..., x_1*z_J,   x_2*z_1 ..... x_K*z_J ]$, where $*$ represents the component wise multiplication, such that $x_k * z_j$ is of size $n\times 1$.

Comment: Why do you want to have the short notation? Condensing information like this mostly makes sense when there is a conceptual reason to do it. (A good indicator would be that you then apply known formulas for the chosen product.) If you only pack and unpack the notation, there’s not much sense in doing it.

Comment: That said, what you want is also a bit strange. In particular, you’re “flattening” away one dimension in the matrix $M$. I would expect a $K \times J$ matrix of vectors of size $n$ (instead of a $n \times (KJ)$ matrix); in other words, a three-dimensional tensor. You might look into [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) and how to express Hadamard-like products in it.